# jqGrid disable column sort after creation depending on some externale data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm looking for solution which gives ability to disable column sort in
jqGrid table after creation, is that even possible? how to do that?

Problem in depth:
First I defined a jqGrid and then offer to pick up some filter fields and then return data regarded to chosen filters, code will looks like this

```
jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"/getUsers/?site="+site+",page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
$('#results').show();
```

so need something regarded if site have been picked up or not to allow sorting on id column, or disable sorting on "id" column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jqGrid bind `click` event handler on every sortable column header to a function which sort the data. To disable column sorting on a column you can unbind the `click` event. If you have column with the name 'colName' for example and the grid with id="list" the id of `<th>` element (the column header) will be "list_colName". So to disable the sorting you can do the following:

```js
var $grid = $("#list"), columnName = 'colName',
    $th = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id) + "_" + columnName);

$th.unbind("click");
$th.children("div.ui-jqgrid-sortable").css("cursor", "default");
```

The last line set additionally default cursor on the column header to show more clear that the column is not sortable.

Comment: Is there a way maybe later to bind it again and how? I know there is way to bind but what would be proper handler functionality?

Comment: I think that you can get the old (the original) handler if you examine `.data('events')` of `$th` before unbind it. It contains all event handler of all registered events.